# Call TypeScript function in HTML without a click event

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular

I know how to call a TypeScript when clicking a button, but how do you call a function without that type of event? I would like to call a function when I have an array called chartData populated. This is what I have:

```
        <div *ngIf="chartData.length">
            chartMethod();
        </div>
```

But instead of `chartMethod()` being called, it just prints 'chartMethod()' on the html page.

I've also tried:

```
            <script> 
                chartTest();
            </script>
```

but the function was still not called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happens because this `chartTest()` is incapsulated by Angular and is not accessible outside Angular.
But inside angular you can, you just need to:

```
<div *ngIf="chartData.length">
    {{chartMethod()}}
</div>
```

But it will add an undefined in html so just test

```
<div *ngIf="chartData.length">
    {{chartMethod() ? chartMethod() : ""}}
</div>
```

But I don't think it's html resposibillity call any method, it needs to be done by the component itself in typescript.

Answer (score 1):

**Angular 2**,
You can call a method automatically by passing a method 'checkFieldAccess()'  in **[ngClass]**
In template file write this

```
 [ngClass]="{check:checkFieldAccess(dataPass)}"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your component.ts put his after constructor

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.getUser();//Put here your function or what you need
  }
```

ngAfterViewInit() is called after a component's view, and its children's views, are created.
Its a lifecycle hook that is called after a component's view has been fully initialized.