# Component calling methods twice

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to filter existing objects of type Worklog and summarize the time spent on each one in my PeriodViewTable component. I'm having a problem with duplicate method calls.

I've tried to fix the problem with resetting the value in ngOnInit(), but it only partially solves the problem - the user sees the correct value, but it's still wrong behind the scenes and console outputs "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError". What is more, the methods are recalled each time I click on DatePicker elements in Form component - which is a different one.

Here's my PeriodViewTable component:

```
<div *ngIf="datesBetween.length > 0 && (filterType == 6 || filterType == 5)">
  <div class="container container-fluid">
    <mat-checkbox #hide [checked]="true">
      <label>Show overview</label>
    </mat-checkbox>
  </div>
  <table *ngIf="hide.checked" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Issue</th>
      <th *ngFor="let date of datesBetween">{{date}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let wrk of worklogs">
      <td>{{wrk.issueKey}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let date of datesBetween">{{getWorklogTimeForDay(wrk, datesBetween.indexOf(date))}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th *ngFor="let date of datesBetween">{{getTotalTimeForDay(datesBetween.indexOf(date))}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Total for period</th>
      <th>{{periodTotal}}</th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

So for example, if I have 5 entries in the `worklogs` array and selected 2 days, the `getWorklogTimeForDay` method should be called 10 times - for each entry in the array * amount of days. Also, the `getTotalTimeForDay` method should be called once for each day, so here 2 times total. For some reason, the process is done twice. As I said before, it's also triggered after I click on any of the DatePicker HTML elements in a different component - Form component. This moment is where I'm totally lost. Here's its HTML code:

```
<div class="container container-fluid">
  <div class="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input #tfDomain type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Domain address" value="jira-test">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">.atlassian.net</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input #tfProject type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type project name here" value="TEST">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input #tfUser type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" value="user.name">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">@testmail.com</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input #pfPassword type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="passwrd123">
      </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Filters</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input #userFilter type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" value="user.filter"
                 [disabled]="startDate.value.length>0 && chbRefresh.checked">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">@testmail.com</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input #startDate matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Start date"
                 [disabled]="userFilter.value.length>0 && chbRefresh.checked">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input #endDate matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="End date"
                 [disabled]="userFilter.value.length>0 && chbRefresh.checked">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="searchButton"
                (click)="submitAll(tfDomain.value, tfProject.value, tfUser.value, pfPassword.value, chbRefresh.checked, userFilter.value, startDate.value, endDate.value)">
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <mat-checkbox #chbRefresh [disabled]="userFilter.value.length > 0 && startDate.value.length > 0"
                      [checked]="true">
          <label>Refresh search</label>
        </mat-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The PeriodViewTable typescript file:

```
export class PeriodViewTableComponent implements OnInit {

  datesBetween: string[];
  worklogs: Worklog[] = [];
  newSearch: boolean;
  filterType: number = 0;
  periodTotal: number = 0;
  someint: number = 0;
  someint2: number = 0;

  constructor(private formService: FormService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit() - period view table');
    this.formService.newSearchChanged.subscribe(
      newSearch => {
        if(newSearch != this.newSearch) {
          this.worklogs = [];
          this.periodTotal = 0;
        }
      }
    );
    this.formService.filterChanged.subscribe(filterType => this.filterType = filterType);
    console.log('filterChanged');
    this.datesBetween = this.formService.datesBetweenChanged.subscribe( dates => this.datesBetween = dates);
    this.formService.worklogsChanged.subscribe(worklog => this.worklogs.push(worklog));
  }

  getWorklogTimeForDay(wrk: Worklog, index: number){
    console.log('getWorklogTimeForDay(' + wrk + ', ' + index + ')'+ '    ' + this.someint++);
    let currentDate = new Date(this.datesBetween[index]);
    if(moment(wrk.started).startOf('day').isSame(moment(currentDate).startOf('day'))) {
      return wrk.timeSpentSeconds/3600;
    }else return '-';
  }

  getTotalTimeForDay(index: number) {
    console.log('getTotalTimeForDay(' + index + ')' + '    ' + this.someint2++);
    let total: number = 0;
    for(let wrk of this.worklogs){
      if(moment(wrk.started).startOf('day').isSame(moment(this.datesBetween[index]).startOf('day'))){
        total += wrk.timeSpentSeconds/3600;
      }
    }
    this.periodTotal += total;
    return total;
  }

}
```

Below is link to the screenshot of what I see in the console. As you can see, the process is repeated twice:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZS5V.jpg
And how it looks like, visualized:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj3HC.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrM8h.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The reason both methods are triggered more often than they supposed to is that `{{someMethodCall()}}` is triggered each time the component is rendered. So on changing anything in the component - the methods are being called.

Here's a quick [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckngdg)

I would advice you not to use methods inside string interpolation.

On how to fix this problem - please consider creating a custom pipe for each of the methods you need. The pipe will be triggered only if the data is changed, thus giving you the expected behavior.

**UPDATE**

> You can also use getters instead of pipes, since [some pipes are
>   discouraged](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe) – @trichetriche

Comment: You can also use getters instead of pipes, since [some pipes are discouraged](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

Comment: can you somehow show a link to an example where such pipe/getter is used? i'm still pretty new to angular and thought string interpolation was the only way to use typescript methods. it's also used e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380212/call-typescript-function-in-html-without-a-click-event/38380320

Comment: I've updated my example with a custom pipe and it's use. You can check it out.

Comment: @Jack_Russell If you are satisfied with my answer could you please mark it as 'answered'?

Comment: i just realized that in your example theres the same error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" take a look at the console display after you click the "Do a dance" button

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right. The reason for that is the fact that I have `{{generateAString()}}` in my html file, if you remove it - the error goes away.  If you have that error - try reading this article on how to salve it https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides whole life cycle of component and change detection mechanism. If you have any getter / setter or function on your template, **it will be called with every change detection cycle**. And Angular runs a lot of that cycles. That's why you should never have any getter, setter or function on template - remember that. You should only bind properties (which are variables which are not functions). If that data does not change during component's life, calculate it inside `ngOnInit()`.

For me, you should definitely calculate everything you need to even before `*ngFor` is being called (like for example, after receiving data from observable).

Recommending [How does Angular2 change detection really works?](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/), it should get you understand the topic.

Comment: so from what I've understood, somewhere in my typescript code, I should create a method that would return two arrays - one for getWorklogTimeForDay method, and another one for getTotalTimeForDay, and then *ngFor using them? but how/where exacly should my component listen to their changes?