# How to display an array item's attribute based on an incoming value from restapi?

Tags: arrays, angular

In an input form, I am showing a list of textual values in drop down and storing an index value of the user selected item in the back end table.

For example, I have an array like this. In the input form, I am showing the `name` attribute in the dropdown, but storing `value` attribute in the table.

```
NEIGHBOURHOOD_TYPES = [
    {value: 1, name: 'School'},
    {value: 2, name: 'College'},
    {value: 3, name: 'Hospital'}
];
```

In a display screen of that same data, I am fetching the records from table and i am getting `value` 1,2,3, etc. I want to show its corresponding `name` attribute in a simple `<td>` element.

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <!-- Type Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Type </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.neighbourhoodType}} </td>
    </ng-container>
```

showing 1,2,etc. But I want it to show its corresponding `name` attribute.

what is the simplest and best option to do it?

[Refer the screen shot of the usage screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXwDb.png)

(sorry for this naive question, but I am new to angular.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from these two threads.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580100/typescript-take-object-out-of-array-based-on-attribute-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380212/call-typescript-function-in-html-without-a-click-event/38380320)

[Call TypeScript function in HTML without a click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380212/call-typescript-function-in-html-without-a-click-event/38380320)

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Type </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{getNeighbourhoodTypeName(row.neighbourhoodType)}} </td>
    </ng-container>
```

Had a write a tiny function in the ts file

```
  getNeighbourhoodTypeName(val):string {
    return this.NEIGHBOURHOOD_TYPES.find(nType => nType.value === val).name;
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use *ngFor attribute.

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of NEIGHBOURHOOD_TYPES">
        <td>{{item.value}} +' : '+{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I do not want to show all values of that array, rather want to show only the item that user has saved in the backed table.  (please refer my updated edit and screenshot and code snippet)